# Am I using handlers in the wrong way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler, ashx, handlers

I've never used HTTP Handlers before, and I've got one working, but I'm not sure if I'm actually using it properly. I have generated a string which will be saved as a CSV file. When the user clicks a button, I want the `download dialog` box to open so that the user can save the file. What I have works, but I keep reading about modifying the `web.config` file and I haven't had to do that.

My Handler:

```
private string _data;
private string _title = "temp";


public void AddData(string data)
{
    _data = data;
}



public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return false; }
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","filename=" + _title + ".csv");
    context.Response.Write(_data);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.Close();

}
```

And this is from the page that allows the user to download:
(on button click)

```
string dataToConvert = "MYCSVDATA....";

csvHandler handler = new csvHandler();
handler.AddData(dataToConvert);

handler.ProcessRequest(this.Context);
```

This works fine, but no examples I've seen ever instantiate the handler and always seem to modify the web.config. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that it's not really using the fact that it's a handler at all. What is the benefit in making a separate class for this implementing an interface you don't really use, rather than putting the code within your existing page class? You're only doing things to the response - so why not just do that within the page?

The typical approach of modifying web.config is because you want the handler to actually handle the request - whereas in your case the page is receiving the request, and just asking an object which *happens* to implement the handler interface to dump the data into the response.

In particular, would this handler be usable at all as a standalone handler for a normal response? It feels like it's only going to do anything useful when you've called `AddData` on it... if you *did* register it in web.config, it would just respond with an empty csv file (or possibly an exception), right? If that's the case, I really don't think it should implement the `IHttpHandler` in the first place - it will mislead other developers who look at it later.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I originally had it in the code page, but I read a forum post where someone said that it would be more efficient to use a handler to allow users to download. I guess their scenario must've been different (i.e. doing more than just using the response property).